# modsecurity3: replace rule with a custom one for a specific URI

Tags: mod-security, drupal

In a crs 3.2 there is a rule with ID=941320 which prevents CKEditor to work within drupal.

CKEditor is a wysiwyg that produces html and attempts to upload it to server. Modsecurity 3 with crs blocks such a request then.

To mitigate false positives I did clone original rule 941320 and modify a list of html tags.
Now my custom rule is saved in RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS.conf file and uses dedicated, unique ruleID. New, custom rule operates on reduced subset of html tags which are still forbidden. Some common html tags were deleted from blacklist and should be passed through.

How to replace rule 941320 with my rule 9001121 for an URI like "/private-message/create" ?

Answer (score 0):

First you must create an exclusion to avoid activating rule `941320` when the URI is what you given:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@streq /private-message/create" \
    "id:9001120,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleRemoveById=941320"
```

then if you want to control the request for that endpoint, you can create a chained rule:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@streq /private-message/create" \
    "id:9001121,
    phase:2,
    block,\
    capture,\
    t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,t:jsDecode,t:lowercase,\
    msg:'Possible XSS Attack Detected - HTML Tag Handler',\
    logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',\
    tag:'application-multi',\
    tag:'language-multi',\
    tag:'platform-multi',\
    tag:'attack-xss',\
    tag:'OWASP_CRS',\
    tag:'capec/1000/152/242/63',\
    tag:'PCI/6.5.1',\
    tag:'paranoia-level/2',\
    ver:'OWASP_CRS/3.3.0',\
    severity:'CRITICAL',\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "@rx <your-modified-pattern...\W" \
        setvar:'tx.xss_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score}',\
        setvar:'tx.anomaly_score_pl2=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score}'"
```

or something similar... You can see that the second part of the last chained rule is same that the original rule. Don't forget to put your own pattern to argument.

You have to place it to your custom exclusion ruleset, eg. `REQUEST-903.9010-custom-exclusions.conf`, and include it to your server (`*.conf` is enough)